# Is there a hex editor component for recent Delphi versions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2010, hex-editors

I've been able to find a few hex controls by searching online, but none that will compile under Unicode.  Does anyone know if there is one available?

Comment: I have compiled Colin Wilson's cmpHexEdit unit, part of his ResourceEditorComponents library, used in his resource editor.  It's compiling, but isn't quite working right with widestrings.  I'm still looking, but could probably get this to work if I don't find something better.  What did you end up using?

Comment: @Chris: I ended up using KHexEditor.  I didn't need it to actually display Unicode characters correctly; just that it would compile and display binary files properly under Unicode-enabled versions of Delphi.

Comment: Thanks Mason, I do need it to render the unicode chars, so I'm going with ATBinHex.  I had previously been using Colin Wilson's, which now apparently supports editing (mine was old) but doesn't handle Unicode right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [KHexEditor](http://www.tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/khexeditor.html) has support for D2009 and D2010, but not tried, I'm currently using D2007...

Comment: on the website they say that D2010 is supported

Comment: I tried the demo and opened a Unicode file with Russian and Chinese characters. Didn't display properly.  So I'm still looking...

Answer (score 4):

Alexey Torgashin's [ATBinHex](http://atviewer.sourceforge.net/atbinhex.htm) and [ATViewer](http://atviewer.sourceforge.net/atviewer.htm) . Did not tried it with unicode delphi versions, but it supports Delphi 2009.

Comment: The demo seems to work nicely, including a "Unicode/Hex" view that renders a unicode file perfectly, with mixed Cryllic/Chinese/English text in the text area, while showing the hex view. Nice.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to install 3 additional libraries in order to compile the demo.... bummer.  OSS, I guess I can't complain too much.

Comment: ATBinHex link broken.

Comment: ATBinHex link broken - does anybody has a new link?

Answer (score 0):

I think SynEditPlus also has a hex editor control:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/synedit/index.php?title=SynEdit_Home_Page